# Is it possibe to extrapolate abundance estimates of N-mixture models to unsampled parts of a species range?

Tags: r, mixed-model, biostatistics, spatial, spatial-correlation

I have repeated count data for a part of the range of the species I am interested in, and have used unmarked to get an abundance estimate for these. My understanding is that the population estimate from the N-mixture model is an estimate for the population of the counted areas; is there a way to extrapolate this to the rest of the study region?

Or do I just have to use a Species Distribution Model like MaxEnt to estimate the distribution of the species, see the percent of the species range which is covered by the sample areas, and estimate the population by calculating

(Sample Area)/(SDM Estimated Species Range) = (N-Mixed Population)/(Total Population)?

I have used the `unmarked` package in R to do the N-mixed abundance model.